# Heroku. Run sql to prepare DB. Posgtresql 9.3. Python

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, cloud, tornado

I have prepared app on heroku and nned to prepare db.

I need just to run sql to create db and create user roles, function, tables etc.

But the problem is that I do not have premission for that.

I get the following errors:

```
DROP SCHEMA
ERROR: database "operations_research" does not exist
ERROR: permission denied to drop role
CREATE SCHEMA
ERROR: permission denied to create databas
```

The sql is correct (the full app is working on Ubuntu server/Windows 8.1).
Usually I run sql with *postgres* user.

Could you please help me how can I just run the sql? I have **googled** and found a message on a forum that I can't create roles and create db if I use Heroku Cloud platform. Is it true?

In this case Coudl you please advice me what Cloud Services or VPS/VSD should I use for tornado + posgresql?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create dbs or roles on Heroku, and there is no reason to want to do so. You request one via the Postgres add-on and use it in your code.